# Install Shield LE zip previous or back up files instead of overwriting

Tags: visual-studio, zip, installshield

I would like to know if it possible to configure Install shield LE (Visual Studio) to detect previous installed files and the zip those files before progressing without overwriting the files. Hope this makes sense? for instance files are detected and zipped before new files are installed into the same folder destination. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It may not be completely impossible, but it would require significant custom code, and probably would require sequencing locations for custom actions that are only available in InstallShield's Professional edition and higher.